# SharePoint 2013 - Column Filtering

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, filter

I have a question about odd behaviour with column filtering on a List in SP2013.

I have two columns in my list that I want to be able to do adhoc filtering on.

*Columns*:

**Year**: Managed Metadata type, containing years

**Document Type**: Choice type, containing a list of options

If I pick an item to filter from in the Document Type, such as "budgets", then try to select a year to filter for in the Year Column, the filter on the year column does not work properly. Even though I have selected "2016" as the filter for the Year, it is showing me items from multiple different years.

However, if i filter using the Year column ONLY, the filter works. Also, if i apply the filters in the reverse order (first applying year filter, then document type filter) it also works.

Why does the order of applying filters matter?

thank you